# what is 'write' in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I read the documentation from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas), Firebase has some limitations. I can only write 10000 documents per second.

```
Maximum writes per second per database  10,000 (up to 10 MiB per second)
```

what is 'write' in here ? obviously it is not reading a document.

create, update and delete document ?

or it is just create a document considered as write ?

Answer (score 1):

It is [set as well as updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations). One document created is one write. If the same document is updated later then it Firebase counts it as one more write.